# Case insensitive Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have following Python regex:

```
re =re.match(r'.*? from\s+(.*?)(\s.*|$)', q)
```

Here, q is a query like this:

```
Q1 = u"select * from dlpx_jobs where job_id=\\'531\\';"

Q2 = u"select * FROM dlpx_jobs where job_id=\\'531\\';"
```

Now, obviously, for Q1 the regex works because "from" is lowercase in the query but for Q2 regex doesn't work because in Q2 "from" is in Uppercase.

Is there any way through which the regex works for both the query irrespective of whether "from" is uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: use inline modifier `(?i)`

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
expr = re.match(r'.? from\s+(.?)(\s.*|$)', q, re.IGNORECASE)
```